# Coinbase API - transfer between currencies, EOS-BTC

Tags: coinbase-api

In the API reference I see buy/sell, that requires a FIAT token. Is there an option in the Coinbase API that will allow me to transfer/convert from one wallet to another, say EOS to BTC ?  or actually I want to transfer between USDC and BTC ?